# Attempting to connect to MSSQL with django-pyodbc-azure results in file not found error

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

I think my question is more or less a duplicate of [Trying to query SQL Server from django running on Linux - Can't open lib '/path/to/libtdsodbc.so'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488287/trying-to-query-sql-server-from-django-running-on-linux-cant-open-lib-path), but the answer there is wholly not useful.

I am using the following things:

1. Ubuntu 15.04
2. `Python3`
3. `Django 1.9` (installed via pip3)
4. `freetds-dev 0.91-6build1` installed via apt-get
5. `django-pyodbc-azure`/`django-pyodbc` installed via pip3
6. MSSQL 2012

When attempting to connect, doing a `python3 manage.py inspectdb` I get the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 302, in get_new_connection
    timeout=timeout)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 25, in handle
    for line in self.handle_inspection(options):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 38, in handle_inspection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 302, in get_new_connection
    timeout=timeout)
django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I've edited base.py to print out the connection string it's using, which is:

```
DRIVER=FreeTDS;DATABASE=test;PWD=test;UID=sa;PORT=1433;SERVER=10.13.36.223
```

My settings.py for the database looks like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'sa',
    'PASSWORD': 'test',
    'HOST': '10.13.36.223',
    'PORT': '1433',
    'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'host_is_server': True
        }
    }
}
```

My assumption is that the `DRIVER` portion of the connection str should be the fully qualified path to the executable for the odbc driver, and that right now it's set to "FreeTDS", which doesn't exist as a file. My questions then are:

1. If my assumption is correct, how do I change the value for the driver?
2. If my assumption is incorrect, what is actually wrong, and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed to do the following:

1. `sudo apt-get install tdsodbc`
2. edit `/etc/odbcinst.ini` to include the following:

.

```
  [FreeTDS]
  Description = TDS Driver for MSSQL
  driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
  setup =  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The above [FreeTDS] configuration is very helpful.

In settings.py DATABASE session, I also add drivers version as well as unicode results setups.  Here is my config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'myDataBaseNameInMSSQLServer',
        'USER': 'mssql-user-with-SQL-authentication',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'server-host-name-or-IP\\SQLEXPRESS',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
            'host_is_server': True,
            'unicode_results': True,
            'driver': 'FreeTDS',
            'extra_params' : 'TDS_VERSION=8.0',
            }
    }
}
```

For SQL Express, you will also need to Google search for how to make that instance available for remote connection.