# Django SystemCheckError Says Pillow Not Installed, but Pillow is Installed

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

When I run `python manage.py runserver`, everything starts out fine, but then I get a `SystemCheckError` stating that Pillow is not installed; however, Pillow is definitely installed on this machine.

This is the error I receive:

> Performing system checks...
>
> Unhandled exception in thread started by  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 225, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
>   line 110, in inner_run
>       self.validate(display_num_errors=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 468, in validate
>       return self.check(app_configs=app_configs, display_num_errors=display_num_errors)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 527, in check
>       raise SystemCheckError(msg) django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System
>   check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS: recipes.Recipes.primary_image: (fields.E210) Cannot use
>   ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
>           HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install Pillow". recipes.Recipes.thumbnail_image:
>   (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
>           HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install Pillow".

I'm running this on an Ubuntu machine. Any ideas what's up?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: pip freeze...does it show up?

Comment: Yes, pip freeze shows Pillow==2.9.0. I am not using a virtualenv. I have connected to an EC2 Linux instance from Windows using PuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if you have anywhere tried to use the import statements like `import pillow` or `from pillow import ...`, change those statements to:

```
from PIL import ...
```

or

```
import PIL
```

[`PIL`](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) i.e Python Imaging Library is no longer maintained, [`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/index.html#pillow) is used instead. To maintain backwards compatibility, `PIL` module name is used in imports.

Comment: I do not have 'import pillow' or 'from pillow import...' anywhere in my code.

Comment: Check if `PIL` is also installed along with `pillow`. If it is, then uninstall `PIL`.

Comment: PIL is not installed.

Comment: Go to Django shell and try the command `from PIL import Image`. Check if that works correctly

Comment: When I try the command you suggest, the following error occurs:

>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 63, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: libopenjp2.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: This might be due to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  check these links. 1. https://community.webfaction.com/questions/18564/pillow-unable-to-find-libopenjp2so7-despite-being-in-ld_library_path  2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545580/pil-libjpeg-so-8-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61063514/2254794

Short version: pillow requires libjpeg and libzlib at runtime; django will report any `import PIL` failure as the error seen above.