# AWS Lambda : How to use Pillow library?

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create an AWS lambda function in order to create thumbnail of my uploaded images. 
My script is running well locally, I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) to deploy my function but I have a problem with the Pillow library, indeed when I'm testing my function I can see this following log :

[image]

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545580/pil-libjpeg-so-8-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory) with the same issue but in my case I can't execute command line on the machine.

Comment: Solution: look here https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages/tree/master/lambda_packages - they have precompiled PIL packages

Comment: Hey, I posted a solution here that does not require Docker. You just create a layer, the trick being that you have the correct version of Python locally, which you can install if needed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74736780/1375627

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must include the `libjpeg.so` in your lambda package, but it will also require some tweaking with the [patchelf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/patchelf.1.html) utility. Assuming that you prepare the lambda package via "`pip install` *module-name* `-t`" (rather than via `virtualenv`), do the following:

```
cd into/your/local/lambda/package/dir
cp -L $(ldd PIL/_imaging.so|grep libjpeg|awk '{print $3}') PIL/
patchelf --set-rpath PIL PIL/_imaging.so
# zip, deploy and test the package
```

This script works for Pillow version 3.2.0.

Regarding `patchelf`: under Ubuntu it can be `'apt install'`ed, but under other Linuxes it may need to be [built from source](https://nixos.org/releases/patchelf/patchelf-0.9/).

Comment: It is strange, but it works only if I add the following line ```sys.path.append("./PIL")```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Pillow uses native libraries that must be built for the exact correct environment.

I solved this by installing my requirements in a Docker container that replicates very closely the AWS Lambda environment, [lambci/lambda](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/). I used the `build-python3.8` version.

I installed my requirements there and zipped up the whole contents of `/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` directory along with my lambda function file.

I tried this with a standard Amazon Linux Docker image and it didn't work. Only the lambci/lambda image worked for me.