# ImportError: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: django, exception, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

There is this similar question:
[PIL - libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545580/pil-libjpeg-so-8-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

But I get a slightly different output:

```
$ python manage.py               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "some_virtualenv/lib64/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "some_django_project/some_django_app/models.py", line 25, in <module>
    from versatileimagefield.fields import VersatileImageField
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/versatileimagefield/fields.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .files import VersatileImageFieldFile, VersatileImageFileDescriptor
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/versatileimagefield/files.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .mixins import VersatileImageMixIn
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/versatileimagefield/mixins.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .datastructures import FilterLibrary
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/versatileimagefield/datastructures/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .sizedimage import SizedImage
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/versatileimagefield/datastructures/sizedimage.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .base import ProcessedImage
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/versatileimagefield/datastructures/base.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "some_virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 66, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Line 25 in my `models.py`:

```
from versatileimagefield.fields import VersatileImageField
```

Django version:

```
$ pip freeze | grep Django   
Django==1.9.5
```

Pillow version:

```
$ pip freeze | grep Pillow
Pillow==3.2.0
```

System:

```
$ uname -a                        
Linux zbookhack-gableroux-local 4.9.3-200.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 13  01:01:13 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

libjpeg is installed on my system

```
$ sudo dnf install libjpeg
Package libjpeg-turbo-1.5.1-0.fc25.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Package libjpeg-turbo-1.5.1-0.fc25.i686 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow) fixed this in version **3.3 and above**, upgrading the package did work for me :)

```
pip install Pillow==4
```

or

```
pip install Pillow --upgrade
```

Here are some related Pillow issues on github:

[#1952](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1952)
[#2123](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2123)
[#2167](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2167)