# Tried to import _mysql through MySQLdb and get the error

Tags: python, mysql, django, ubuntu, mysql-python

I'm trying to use MySQLdb and when I try to import it I get the following error. Any thoughts? I'm currently using an ubuntu instance on aws.

```
 >>> import MySQLdb
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
        import _mysql
    ImportError: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 >>>
```

Comment: how did you install mysqldb? from apt-get or pip/easy_install?

Answer (score 2):

Is libmysqlclient-dev installed? Package might not be exact, but thats the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this comment thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/2csDd2YH1H4) of any help?

Try updating /etc/ld.so.conf so as to include the directory in which you've installed this.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this same issue myself (on the AWS Linux I AMI), I found the answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099981/why-cant-python-find-shared-objects-that-are-in-directories-in-sys-path/1100016):

While the [comment thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/2csDd2YH1H4) already posted was helpful, Apache was clearing my environment variables, so setting LD_RUN_PATH and/or LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not effective.

What ended up working was adding a new include statement to /etc/ld.so.conf and running ldconfig.