# Installing PyCURL to a particular version of Python

Tags: python, installation, yum, pycurl

I have Python 2.4 and 2.7 on my Centos server.
I would like to use PyCURL under Python 2.7.
I ran yum install pycurl and it appeared to install but when I attempt to import PyCURL it works fine for Python 2.4 but not for 2.7.
Can anyone advise how it is possible to install PyCURL (or any other Python extension for that matter as I can see this being an issue in future) to a specific version of python.
Thanks
C

------ SOULTION (thanks gjallar) ----------

Instead of using YUM I downloaded and installed PyCurl by running the setup.py file using the python version I wanted i.e.

```
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```

This still didn't work as I was getting an error saying I had the wrong version of libcurl

To ressolve this I downloaded the latest curl version from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and installed with the instructions here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html

Sadly, this still didn't work as when I tried to import pycurl in python I got:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This was in turn ressolved by carrying out the command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

As suggested in the post:
[Why can't Python find shared objects that are in directories in sys.path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099981/why-cant-python-find-shared-objects-that-are-in-directories-in-sys-path)
(Thanks Vinay)

Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible route you can take to install a certain application for a specific python version is to install `pip` using the specific python version and the use `pip` to install `pyCURL`.

In your case this should work by installing `pip` using `python2.7` and then run `pip install pycurl`:

Install pip via [`distribute`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) running the setup.py file with your python2.7 interpreter.

This requires pycurl to be available in [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org) - otherwise (if the pycurl download contains a setup.py) simple run the setup.py file using the interpreter you want to install it for.

Comment: Thanks very much Gjallar, that sorted it.