# pyexiv2 import error libexiv2.so.12 not found

Tags: python

I'm running Centos 6.3 with python 2.6 and trying to use pyexiv2, but I'm getting an import error, file not found when I import pyexiv2. Here is the text of the error

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chuck/bin/pylib/test.py", line 13, in 
    import pyexiv2
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pyexiv2/__init__.py", line 60, in 
    import libexiv2python
ImportError: libexiv2.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, libexiv2.so.12 is in /usr/local/lib. How can I make this visible to python?

How I installed pyexiv2:
I removed the stock exiv2 and built the latest version, 0.23, from source. I used the build defaults and it installed into /usr/local. I installed the stock boost libraries, version 1.41.  I downloaded the latest pyexiv2 and built that using the recommended build tool scons. After I got the import error I put a soft link to libexiv2.so.12 in /lib. Also, my ld.so.conf contains a listing for /usr/local/lib.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered well in a different thread on stackoverflow [Why can't Python find shared objects that are in directories in sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099981/why-cant-python-find-shared-objects-that-are-in-directories-in-sys-path). It turns out I forgot to run ldconfig after adding entries to /etc/ld.so.conf. Oops. Adding /usr/local/lib to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and having an active entry in /etc/ld.so.conf both solved my problem.