# How to upgrade sqlite3 in python 2.7.3 inside a virtualenv?

Tags: python, sqlite, virtualenv

There is a sqlite3 library that comes with python 2.7.3, but it is hardly the latest version.

I would like to upgrade it within a virtualenv environment. In other words, the upgrade only applies to the version of python installed within this virtualenv.

What is the correct way to do so?

Comment: Out of time for now: it should be possible by using the `pysqlite` package, as long as it'll pick up the newer sqlite version when being compiled. The virtual env would need to be extended to point to the new sqlite library when active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below works for me, but please comment if there is any room for improvement:

1. Activate the virtualenv to which you are going to install the latest `sqlite3`
2. Get the latest source of `pysqlite` package from google code: `wget http://pysqlite.googlecode.com/files/pysqlite-2.6.3.tar.gz`
3. Compile `pysqlite` from source and together with the *latest* `sqlite` database: `python setup.py build_static`
4. Install it to the **site-packages** directory of the virtualenv: `python setup.py install`
5. The above will actually install the `pysqlite` into `path-to-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, which is where all other pip-installed libraries are.

Now, I have the latest version of `sqlite` (compiled into `pysqlite`) installed within a virtualenv, so I can do: `from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite`

Comment: thank you so much!!! this fixed my "cannot import name utils" error when trying to use sqlite in django

Comment: The Google Code link is no longer valid. It can be found at: `https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pysqlite/pysqlite-2.6.3.tar.gz`

Comment: Note that pysqlite is Python 2 only. Python 3 folks are out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

I checked setting something like this, works:

```
export export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/<your-sqlite-install-dir>/sqlite3/lib
```

I’ve added it next to the line `export PATH` in the `activate` file:

```
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/…/sqlite3/lib  # <- Here
```

One can check it in either one of two ways.

From Python in the *virtualenv*, first do:

```
>>> import _sqlite3
>>> _sqlite3.__file__
'/usr/lib/…/_sqlite3.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so'
```

Then exit Python and run `ldd` on the string returned:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/…/_sqlite3.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so
> …
> libsqlite3.so.0 => /home/…/sqlite3/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
> …
```

Or alternatively, again in Python from the *virtualenv*:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.21.0'  # Was 3.11.8 before
```

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in the same problem once. This solved it for me:

1. Download and untar the python version required
2. mkdir local
3. untar sqlite after downloading its package
4. ./configure --prefix=/home/aanuj/local
5. make
6. make install
7. ./configure --prefix=/home/anauj/local LDFLAGS='-L/home/aaanuj/local/lib' CPPFLAGS='-I/home/aanuj/local/include'
8. make
9. Find the sqlite3.so and copy to home/desired loc
10. Extract beaver
11. Setup the virtual env with the python version needed
12. Activate the env
13. unalias python
14. export PYTHONPATH=/home/aanuj(location of _sqlite3.so)
15. Enjoy

Comment: But then testing  `sqlite3.sqlite_version`, it still returns the old version.

Comment: This topic contradicts the idea to use PYTHONPATH: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099981/why-cant-python-find-shared-objects-that-are-in-directories-in-sys-path