# undefined symbol: PyOS_mystrnicmp

Tags: python, python-2.x, cpython

I tried installing `pysqlite`, but I'm having some trouble using it.

```
>>> import pysqlite2.dbapi2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysqlite2/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pysqlite2._sqlite import *
ImportError: /data/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysqlite2/_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: PyOS_mystrnicmp
```

I think I might be missing some Python headers. Where do I find them? I'm using CentOS with CPython 2.7.5.

Answer (score 1):

As https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-sqlite/04Ocf7aP1so points out, a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue18603) was reported that appears to be fixed in newer versions of Python. Upgrading to a later version of Python 2.7 did the trick for me.