# Python not using sqlite3 installation

Tags: python, linux, sqlite

I have installed both python 3.9 and sqlite 3.33.0 by compiling from source code.

As shown below:

### sqlite3

```
$ sqlite3 --version

3.33.0 2020-08-14 13:23:32...
```

### Python

```
$ python3 --version

Python 3.9.0
```

However, when I check in python it showed:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version 
'3.7.17
```

After some reading, i have tried

```
$ which sqlite3
/usr/local/bin/sqlite3

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin
```

But this still have not resolved to the issue.

How do I get Python to use my own installation of sqlite?

Any help will be appreciated!

### **Update**

I was able to get python3.9 to use my own installation of sqlite3 by recompiling python with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674176/django-cant-find-new-sqlite-version-sqlite-3-8-3-or-later-is-required-found)

Comment: have you seen my answer? Do update the status of the problem.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by recompiling python3.9 with this guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674176/django-cant-find-new-sqlite-version-sqlite-3-8-3-or-later-is-required-found I need this specific sqlite3 version to use with my django application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've may already figured out, each version of `Python` comes with the latest `SQLite` included so often you are not required to install it manually. Unless this is for a specific use-case, I would highly discourage the use of using your own one.

To solve your current problem (which has been asked many times before), see the answer here - [Python sqlite3: run different sqlite3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282380/python-sqlite3-run-different-sqlite3-version).

You can also set up a customer interpreter for this case, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865416/how-to-use-the-latest-sqlite3-version-in-python) for instructions.

Comment: I set the LD_RUN_PATH during recompiling python to my own sqlite installation and it worked! tahnk you for your help!