# Upgrading SQLite3 version used in python3 on linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, sqlite

I need to upgrade the sqlite3 version that my python 3 uses but there seems to be no clear answers and I don't understand what determines the version of sqlite3 used by python. I am running CentOS7 with python 3.6.4 installed. CentOS had sqlite version 3.7.17 installed and I upgraded this to 3.23.1 thinking python would also use this never version of sqlite.

```
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
```

The following code still gives me 3.17. I have googled how to upgrade the version but most [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282380/python-sqlite3-run-different-sqlite3-version) seem to refer to pysqlite which is python 2 only. Other solutions talk about [complicated compiling processes](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2016/03/18/upgrading-sqlite3-within-python-3/) that go way over my head.

I don't understand what determines the sqlite version that python uses. Is it determined by the python version, OS installed sqlite version? I am also running python 3.6.4 on my windows PC and it says I am running 3.14.2 so it seems that the sqlite version does not depend on the python version.

What determines the sqlite version python uses? Is there not a more straight forward way to upgrade the sqlite version for python 3?

Comment: Python doesn't use the external sqlite3 executable at all, it uses a library that is included in its own distribution. That's why the solutions talk about compiling, that's the only way you can replace it. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Then why does the same version of python on my CentOS and Windows machine have very different versions of sqlite3.
I need the new sqlite version because the indexes I added to my database with foreign keys are not being used with the older sqlite version it seems. When I use the latest version installed on CentOS or the version that is included in with my windows python installation it does make use of my indexes.

Answer (score 9):

sqlite3 is kind of external library.
so, you need to set external library path.

try next command

```
printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

result will be empty, if you never set before.

next command will work using installed sqlite3 for python

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
```

then, you can execute and get correct version you installed

```
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
```

but this method will be reset when you logout and login again.
so, if you want to do regist that environment variable every time you login, you should edit /etc/profile

```
sudo vi /etc/profile
```

and add export code

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
```

then, if you log-out and log-in again, you can see LD_LIBRARY_PATH is registered.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, you can add `dqlite` repository and update it using `apt`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:dqlite/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sqlite3
```