# How do I upgrade the SQLite version used by Python's SQLite3 module on Linux?

Tags: python, django, linux, sqlite

When I am running command python3 mange.py runserver I am getting error improperly configured SQLite 3.8.3 found 3.7 .
Django version is 3.
I also checked similar problems on stackoverflow but in my case it doesn't work

Comment: Are you running the cmd with `root` privileges? To Solve, either upgrade Python to a higher version or downgrade the version of django. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920444/upgrading-sqlite3-version-used-in-python3-on-linux) may also be helpful

Comment: I solved it by reduce sqlite version to sqlite 3.6