# How to change SQLite version used by Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, debian

I have Python 3.8 installed alongside SQLite 3.16.2 on Debian 9.12 and I need to upgrade to a newer version of SQLite. I've downloaded and compiled the amalgamation available on the SQLite's site, and put it in `/usr/bin`, so when I do

```
$ sqlite3 --version
```

I get 3.32.3 in response (which is the version I compiled).

However, when I do

```
$ python3.8
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

I get 3.16.2, which is the earlier version. How do I change the SQLite version picked up by Python?

mkrieger1 suggested that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282380) may answer mine. It won't work here, as the solution provided there is directed at Python 2, not Python 3. `pysqlite2` does not work with Python 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sqlite3: run different sqlite3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282380/python-sqlite3-run-different-sqlite3-version)

Comment: That answer is provided for Python 2, and I'm working with Python 3. `pysqlite2` does not work with Python 3, unfortunately.

Comment: @Xeoth Did I answer your question?

Comment: Do you really need it? It could break some assumption on other python standard lib modules. I think you can recompile Python with the version you want [and check with the test in Python source if it is safe to do so].

Answer (score 7):

In my case I cannot replace with newer version because I cannot find these files. (I installed the sqlite-autoconf-3350500)

I used another manner to let it work just execute below command

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"

>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.35.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go around it, is by finding out the path to the old sqlite version that you are importing:

```py
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.__file__)
```

For me, this outputs:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py
```

Go to the lib path:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib
```

Then find the sqlite3 folder and delete it, then replace it with your up-to-date version. Re-try:

```py
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

You should get your new version.