# Use latest version of SQLite for Python in ubuntu-latest

Tags: python, sqlite, github-actions

I have created a GitHub Actions workflow. which is supposed to run a SQL query. It uses the [arrow operators](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jptr:%7E:text=4.9.-,The%20%2D%3E%20and%20%2D%3E%3E%20operators,-Beginning%20with%20SQLite) for JSON. This requires SQLite >= 3.38.0.

This worked for system with `windows-latest` and `macos-latest`, for which I could say SQLite installed in Python 3.11 was >= 3.38.

But there's a problem I faced in `ubuntu-latest` which has 3.37. I wanted to make sure Python uses the latest version.

I did try installing through `sudo apt -y install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev` but it didn't replace the `sqlite3` version in Python and I got this message:

```
libsqlite3-dev is already the newest version (3.37.2-2ubuntu0.3).
sqlite3 is already the newest version (3.37.2-2ubuntu0.3).
```

reference github workflow:

```
name: 'tests'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'testing'

jobs:
    test:
      name: Test
      runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}


      strategy:
        matrix:
          os: ['macos-latest', 'windows-latest', 'ubuntu-latest']

      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3

        - name: Install Latest sqlite3 version on non-windows platform
          if: ${{ matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest' }}
          run: |
            bash ./.github/scripts/install-sqlite.sh

        - name: Set up Python 3.11
          uses: actions/setup-python@v3
          with:
            python-version: "3.11"

        - name: Install dependencies
          run: |
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install poetry 
            poetry install

        - name: Smoke Test
          run: pytest __test__/test_smoke
```

I have even installed it from the source code, the version changed when I tried `sqlite --version` but it didn't change in Python.

How can I upgrade the `sqlite3` version in Python from 3.37 to 3.38 in `ubuntu-latest`?

Comment: ubuntu-latest uses ubuntu-22.04 and sqlite 3.37 is the latest version available on the offical apt repos. Installing from source seems the way to go. You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523183/how-to-change-sqlite-version-used-by-python and other similar questions to see how to change the sqlite version used by python.

Comment: Since apparently the sqlite3 module is part of the Python standard library, maybe you can get the desired version via the setup-python action? Maybe you use that already, but you don't show your workflow.

Comment: have you considered downloading pre-built binaries?

Comment: @njzk2, I haven't tried through pre-built binaries, I have tried it through source code, will give it a go. Thank you

Comment: @Dhruv, I have tried the solution that was requested, max I still was only able to see 3.37 in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved by **uninstalling existing SQLite** *after* [building it from the source](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

- build the source code of sqlite
- uninstall the existing version through `apt-get remove -y --auto-remove sqlite3`

you would find this in the bash script

```bash
# required to support: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jptr
# installing build: 3.45.0
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2024/sqlite-autoconf-3450000.tar.gz
# unzipping build
tar -xvzf sqlite-autoconf-3450000.tar.gz

# below steps are for installing the build in /usr/local/bin
cd sqlite-autoconf-3450000 || exit
./configure
make
sudo make install

# remove the previous version
sudo apt-get remove -y --auto-remove sqlite3
```

Test Workflow:

```yaml
name: 'server-build'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'server-build'

jobs:
    build:
      name: Building Executable
      needs: pre
      if: ${{ needs.pre.outputs.exists == 'false' }}
      runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
      strategy:
        matrix:
          os: ['macos-latest', 'windows-latest', 'ubuntu-latest']

      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v4

        - name: If in ubuntu, Install sqlite3 3.45.0
          if: ${{ matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest' }}
          run: |
            bash ./build.sh 

        - name: Set up Python 3.11
          uses: actions/setup-python@v5
          with:
            python-version: "3.11"

        - name: check
          run: |
            python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version_info);"
```