# Python SQLAlchemy SQLite FTS unicode6.1 tokenizer

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode, sqlalchemy, full-text-search

This is the code to attempt SQLAlchemy database reflection on a SQLite3 database with FTS tables that use a unicode61 tokenizer:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.sqlite')
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata
metadata.reflect(bind=engine, views=True)
```

This error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unknown tokenizer: unicode61
```

As of v3.8.6 this tokenizer is included by default and is not optionally compiled.

> [v3.8.6 The unicode61 tokenizer is now included in FTS4 by default.](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_6)

Meanwhile when I run:

```
$ python
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqite3.sqlite_version
'3.8.5'
```

... frick.

However:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.9.2 2015-11-02 18:31:45
```

How do I get Python or SQLAlchemy in particular to reference a more modern or even custom compiled sqlite3 binary?

*Additional note*: I am trying to run on an OSX (10.10.5 Yosemite) system so as far as I can tell SQLAlchemy and Python are referencing pysqlite which is the dbapi2 wrapper for sqlite3.dylib. I have just found the following article which I will try and return with my results.

http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/How-to-build-a-new-sqlite3-dylib-td63635.html

*Results so far*:

- Renaming `/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib` in prep for replacing it with
  the custom build will brick OSX and you need to perform a System
  Restore. So I'm going to try a virtualenv approach instead.
- This SO question attempts to replace the sqlite3 library linked in a
  `virtualenv` but I haven't figured out how to apply this to
  SQLAlchemy
  [How to upgrade sqlite3 in python 2.7.3 inside a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541869/how-to-upgrade-sqlite3-in-python-2-7-3-inside-a-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer derived from this StackOverflow Answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546162/622276

1. Download `pysqlite2` source code from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite
2. Download latest SQLite amalgamation source code (v3.9.2 at time of writing) http://www.sqlite.org/download.html (sqlite-amalgamation-3XXXXXX.zip)
3. Extract `pysqlite2` source code.
4. Extract `sqlite3` amalgamation source code.
5. copy `sqlite3` source code into root of where you extracted the `pysqlite2`, eg `path-to/pysqlite-2.X.X`.
6. `cd path-to/pysqlite-2.X.X`
7. `python setup.py build_static`

   This will take the `sqlite3` source code you dumped in the folder and build a static library with the `pysqlite2` module.
8. This will take a minute but there will be a new directory `build` and inside there will be a folder like `lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7`. Inside that you are after the `pysqlite2` folder.

   eg. `path-to/pysqlite2.X.X/build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/pysqlite2`
9. **NOTE: DO THE FOLLOWING AT YOUR OWN RISK. TRY TO USE `virtulenv` WHERE POSSIBLE**. copy this `pysqlite2` folder into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` and overwrite the existing package.
10. SQLAlchemy points to this particular `site-package` of `pysqlite2` for a SQLite wrapper and also the provided static library.

And finally:

```
$ python
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.8.5'
>>> from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.9.2'
```