# Compiling vim against EPD Canopy: no lib/config directory

Tags: python, vim, enthought

I am trying to compile vim against EPD Canopy's python, but the ./configure can't seem to find the correct config directory. Here is the command I am running

```
CC=clang ./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
              --with-features=huge \
              --enable-rubyinterp \
              --enable-pythoninterp \
              --enable-perlinterp \
              --enable-cscope
```

And this is the relevant part of the output

```
checking --enable-pythoninterp argument... yes
checking for python... /Users/noah/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
checking Python version... 2.7
checking Python is 1.4 or better... yep
checking Python's install prefix... /Users/noah/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User
checking Python's execution prefix... /Users/noah/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User
checking Python's configuration directory...
can't find it!
```

Now, there is a `config` directory in the Canopy.app bundle, so I also tried adding the flag `--with-python-config-dir=/Applications/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/config`. Which gave the error

```
checking if compile and link flags for Python are sane... no: PYTHON DISABLED
```

enI am out of ideas. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to run `make distclean` first to get rid of anything cached from your failed builds.

The following *works for me* (on Debian Wheezy 64 bit) (you'll need to change `$VIM_SRC` and `$CANOPY_SRC` to wherever you have your vim and canopy dirs).

```
VIM_SRC=~/src/vim73
CANOPY_SRC=~/src/canopy

cd $VIM_SRC                                                         
make distclean                                                                 
# Compile against canopy python and install in canopy dir, so that             
# this vim is used when canopy is activated.                                   
# YOU HAVE TO HAVE CANOPY ACTIVATED, i.e. `which python` points to canopy   
# you also need python-config 
# (this assumes you can install into your canopy install 
# dir, but it isn't strictly necessary)                                    
APPDATA=$CANOPY_SRC/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64                  
PYTHON_CONFIG=$APPDATA/lib/python2.7/config 
# I'm installing here so that this is the vim used when I start the virtualenv,
# but you can put it where you like. 
INSTALL_DIR=$CANOPY_SRC/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/ 

# force vim to use this python binary                                          
export vi_cv_path_python=$APPDATA/bin/python                                   
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR \                                
    --with-features=big \                                                      
    --enable-pythoninterp=yes \                                                
    --with-python-config-dir=$PYTHON_CONFIG \                                  
    # I didn't actually need these flags. python-config is a helper script
    # that comes with the Debian package python-dev. I'm leaving them here
    # in case someone finds them useful.
    # CFLAGS="`python-config --includes`" \                                      
    # LIBS="`python-config --libs`" \
    # LDFLAGS="`python-config --ldflags`"                                             
make                                                                           
make install
```

The trick is setting `vi_cv_path_python` to force vim to use the python that can import site.

Test with

```
vim -c ':py import os; print os.__file__'
```

This won't be able to import shared objects, e.g `vim -c ':py import zmq'`. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099981/why-cant-python-find-shared-objects-that-are-in-directories-in-sys-path) this.

Call vim after setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
alias vim="LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$APPDATA/lib' vim"
```

#### Problems

Older versions of Vim will fail if you use `CFLAGS="`python-config --cflags`"` or don't give this at all. This is because this includes `-O2` in the gcc args and this will cause vim to [segfault](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/yBL4GkGVUdM/l5fSHMG2dWcJ). This is why I've put `--includes`. **My solution works with the latest [development snapshot](https://github.com/b4winckler/vim/tree/b062f605aa870259b7a4c0dc2b26f47cbb223a92)**.

Comment: I tried again using EPD, and this python-config tip, but no dice :(

Comment: I can get it to compile, but calling `:py` inside Vim crashes it after an error about not finding module Site :(

Comment: I'm on Debian Wheezy 64bit.

Comment: Now you don't have to use `python-config` either. YMMV. I have zero knowledge about OSX or MacVim.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's because Canopy doesn't make a framework the way EPD and system python do, and MacVim uses a -framework option during compile. You can make this work by setting up some symlinks, and modifying a few paths in the compile process.

- First, make a Python.framework symlink in /System/Library to the Python files in /Applications/Canopy.app as follows (modify as needed depending on your version of Canopy): 
  ln -s /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents
- Run the configure script with the options you like (I omit the python-config-dir):
  ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-rubyinterp --enable-pythoninterp --enable-perlinterp --enable-cscope --disable-netbeans
- Modify src/auto/config.mk as follows:

PYTHON_CFLAGS=-I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_HOME='"/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents"'

PYTHON_GETPATH_CFLAGS= ..(whatever is generated by config).... -DPREFIX='"/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0. 3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents"' -DEXEC_PREFIX='"/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.   macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents"'

- Edit src/if_python.c (line 59) to read # include Python.h instead of Python/Python.h
- This should compile correctly. However, there's an rpath issue when running vim that I'm not experienced enough understand (if you know about it, please share). So I get around the issue by simply making a symlink in /usr/lib to the Python library:

ln -s /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/Python /usr/lib/Python

You could also export a DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, but one shouldn't have to do something like this-- an executable should be built knowing where to find its libraries. But as I said, I'm an amateur.