# How to work with CORBA in Python and Java?

Tags: java, python, corba

I'm doing a practice of Distributed Systems subject of my University. We have to do an application which shows the current hour using CORBA where the server is written one language  and client written in other.

I decided to use Python for server and Java for client. And I'm using omniORB for compiling for Python the IDL file.

```
from datetime import *
import sys, os
import CORBA, CosNaming, Util, Util__POA

class Hora_i(Util__POA.Hora):
    def get_hora(self):
        return datetime.today()

orb = CORBA.ORB_init(sys.argv)
poa = orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA")
poa._get_the_POAManager().activate()

servant = Hora_i()
poa.activate_object(servant)
servantObjref = servant._this()

print orb.object_to_string(servant._this())

#horaObjref = servant._this()

nameRoot = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService")
nameRoot = nameRoot._narrow(CosNaming.NamingContext)
try:
    if nameRoot is None:
        print "NameService narrow failed"
        sys.exit(1)
except CORBA.ORB.InvalidName, ex:
    # This should never happen, since "NameService" is always a
    # valid name, even if it hadn't been configured.

    print "Got an InvalidName exception when resolving NameService!"
    sys.exit(1)

except CORBA.NO_RESOURCES, ex:
    print "No NameService configured!"
    sys.exit(1)

except CORBA.SystemException, ex:
    print "System exception trying to resolve and narrow NameService!"
    print ex
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    name = [CosNaming.NameComponent("hora", "")]
    horaContext = nameRoot.bind_new_context(name)
except CosNaming.NamingContext.AlreadyBound, ex:
        # There is already a context named "hora", so we resolve
        # that.
        print 'Reusing "hora" naming context.'

        horaContext = nameRoot.resolve(name)
        horaContext = horaContext._narrow(CosNaming.NamingContext)

        if horaContext is None:
            # Oh dear -- the thing called "hora" isn't a
            # NamingContext. We could replace it, but it's safer to
            # bail out.
            print 'The name "hora" is already bound in the NameService.'
            sys.exit(1)

horaContext.rebind([CosNaming.NameComponent("DarHora","")], servantObjref)
print "DarHora bound in NameService.    "

orb.run()
```

Actually I can compile and run the server side without problems. (I think that)

On the other hand, this is my java code

```
import Util.*;
import org.omg.CORBA.*;
import org.omg.CosNaming.*;

     public class Cliente {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            try{
                ORB orb = ORB.init(args,null);
  // obtener una referencia a NameService
  org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("DarHora");
  // las siguientes lineas nos permiten obtener una ref a un objeto remoto
  NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);
  // nombre del obj remoto
  String nombre = "DarHora";
    Hora impl = HoraHelper.narrow(ncRef.resolve_str(nombre));      
  System.out.println(impl.get_hora());
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("ERROR : " + e);
   e.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
 }
}
```

In java I compile my file but when I try to run it there's an error. This is my stacktrace

```
com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl <init>
WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 127.0.1.1; port: 900"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2200)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2221)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:223)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:236)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.java:119)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.invoke(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.resolve(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:132)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1169)
    at Cliente.main(Cliente.java:10)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:639)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:184)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.java:78)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:206)
    ... 11 more
```

How can I solve?  Please, help me

Comment: `orb.resolve_initial_references("DarHora")` is strange. How come your client isn't going to the NameService to find the server?

Comment: It looks like your Name Service isn't running. Have a look at your ORB's documentation to find out how to run it. It looks like it expects it to be running on localhost:900 but it can't open a connection to it.

Comment: Or it could be that your Java client isn't configured correctly and thinks the Name Service is running on a different port than it really is.

Answer (score 0):

The following were tested in linux-ubuntu platform-

Try to locate your pyhton dist-packages folder. In my case it was `/usr/local/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/`.

After that do the following steps:

1. Open terminal in `/home/<user>`. In my case `/home/sdebnath`.
2. Open file `.bashrc` in ypur preferred editor. Eg. `gedit .bashrc`.
3. Add this line at the end of the file: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<path-to-your-python-dist-packages>`. In my case
   `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/`.
4. Save the file and exit.
5. For the chnages in the `.bashrc` file to take effect, logout from current user and login again.
6. Try executing your code and see problem exists or not.

Find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099981/why-cant-python-find-shared-objects-that-are-in-directories-in-sys-path/77926355#77926355).