# I can't install python package, although required libraries exist

Tags: python

I am trying to install a Python package and I get a dependency error but I am sure I have fulfilled that requirement.

It says that it can't find libdickinson.so, but this library is already installed (system wide) and its files are in `/user/local/lib/`. What am I doing wrong?

This is my console output:

```
(iwidget)chris@mint-desktop ~ $ pip install pthelma
Downloading/unpacking pthelma
  Downloading pthelma-0.7.2.tar.gz (50kB): 50kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pthelma
    libdickinson.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    Please make sure you have installed dickinson
    (see http://dickinson.readthedocs.org/).
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    libdickinson.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory



Please make sure you have installed dickinson

(see http://dickinson.readthedocs.org/).

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/chris/.virtualenvs/iwidget/build/pthelma
Storing complete log in /home/chris/.pip/pip.log
(iwidget)chris@mint-desktop ~ $ ls /usr/local/lib/
libdickinson.a         libdickinson.la        libdickinson.so        libdickinson.so.0      libdickinson.so.0.0.0  python2.7/             python3.2/             site_ruby/
(iwidget)chris@mint-desktop ~ $
```

Comment: try manual istaling without pip.download pthelma

Comment: Could this have to do with the fact you're working in a virtualenv?

Comment: Did you try running `sudo ldconfig` after installing libdickinson.so?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Maybe, I don't really know.

Comment: @javidcf: No, should I?

Comment: @xpanta It depends... If you installed the library by just copying it to /usr/local/lib, or by non-standard means in general (for example, manual compilation), you may need to run that command to add the library to the linker cache. Run it (it's harmless btw) and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also try the above command as superuser:

```
sudo pip install pthelma
```

and just go through the thread given below:

[Why can't Python find shared objects that are in directories in sys.path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1099981/1447634)

Comment: Thanks. The link you provided was helpful. I added `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` in my `.bashrc` and it worked! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try building it yourself and installing from the GIT repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/openmeteo/pthelma.git
```

Also, try running it as super user (pip).

```
sudo pip install pthelma
```

It looks like it can't see the libdickinson.so file but if you're confident it's installed and setup correctly you can, as I said, try cloning the source and building it that way.

Comment: I'd try running as SU first as if it works you don't have the mess of the GIT repo.

Comment: with `sudo pip install pthelma` I get the exact same error. Will try to git-clone it.