# Linux Shared Object File Error

Tags: linux, redhat, shared-objects

Below is the error I get when trying to run a command.

ImportError: libreadline.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or di                                                  rectory

I have updated everything I can even tried to fix shared libraries links.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS tech support.

Comment: you might want to take a look at this question. Look around first, then ask a very precise question... http://stackoverflow.com/q/1099981/2082964

Comment: This is an old library, the error is surprising, why do you have that problem? You must be using some old library.

Comment: Old Response but fixed. I had to run this command  sudo ln -sf /pathtodir/devtools/3.0/lib/libreadline.so.4