# Cannot import pyodbc on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, odbc, pyodbc

I am unable to import `pyodbc` on my Macbook Pro (running Mac OS X 10.10.5) and python version 2.7.10.  I used `pip` to get it, and I have the latest version (3.0.10).  It gives me the following error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyodbc.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SQLAllocHandle
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyodbc.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyodbc.so
```

I have tried several things over the past few months to no avail, including building it myself (and (re-)installing `iodbc` and `unixodbc` along the way).

One of the weird things is that none of the other python database packages I've tried to use (e.g., sqlalchemy, pypyodbc, etc.) work either for various and similar reasons either.  This has led me to suspect some underlying problem with my ODBC driver or library, but I don't know how to diagnose it.

I am working in a shared code environment where the rest of the team is using `pyodbc` via Windows and I *really* need this to work now.  Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

---

**Added more details in reply to mauro's answer.  Note, second update below changes things. **

Here are some more details that I should have included in the original question.

First, here are the results of the commands mauro asked about on my machine.

```
$ odbc_config --version
2.3.2
$ odbc_config --libs
-L/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/lib -lodbc
$ odbc_config --odbcini
/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbc.ini
$ odbc_config --odbcinstini
/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbcinst.ini
```

I was suspicious about the "Cellar" part, so I looked at the paths in mauro's answer and they all seem to point to Cellar (homebrew?) anyway:

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/etc/*odbc*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  39 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbc.ini
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  43 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbcinst.ini

$ ls -al /usr/local/etc/odbc*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  39 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbc.ini
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  43 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbcinst.ini
1395:Stephens-BlueDot-MacBook-Pro:~/BlueDot/Code/Data Processing Tools} ls -al /usr/local/etc/*odbc*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  39 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbc.ini
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  43 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbcinst.ini
1396:Stephens-BlueDot-MacBook-Pro:~/BlueDot/Code/Data Processing Tools} ls -al /usr/local/lib/*odbc*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  46 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  44 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/lib/libodbc.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  48 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/lib/libodbccr.2.dylib@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/lib/libodbccr.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  46 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/lib/libodbccr.dylib@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/lib/libodbccr.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  50 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.2.dylib@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/lib/libodbcinst.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  48 17 Aug 16:57 /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.dylib@ -> ../Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/lib/libodbcinst.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  45 17 Aug 16:59 /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.0.so@ -> ../Cellar/freetds/0.95.18/lib/libtdsodbc.0.so
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  42 17 Aug 16:59 /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.a@ -> ../Cellar/freetds/0.95.18/lib/libtdsodbc.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  admin  43 17 Aug 16:59 /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so@ -> ../Cellar/freetds/0.95.18/lib/libtdsodbc.so

/usr/local/lib/tdbcodbc1.0.0:
total 144
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel    170 29 Mar  2013 ./
drwxrwxr-x  44 root  admin   1496 17 Aug 16:59 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  49796 29 Mar  2013 libtdbcodbc1.0.0.dylib*
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel    245 29 Mar  2013 pkgIndex.tcl
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel  15624 29 Mar  2013 tdbcodbc.tcl
```

I can connect fine to the DNS via `tsql` (specifics anonymized):

```
$ tsql -S servername.myserver.com -U me -P mypw -D testdb
locale is "en_CA.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Setting testdb as default database in login packet
1>
```

But `osql` and `isql` both give problems:

```
$ isql -v MyDSN me mypw
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[01000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unknown host machine name.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

This one gives the most info.  It's finding the DSN entry in my `~/.odbc.ini` file at least.

```
$ osql -S MyDSN -U ***** -P ***** 
checking shared odbc libraries linked to isql for default directories...
/usr/local/bin/osql: line 53: ldd: command not found
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strings: can't open file:  (No such file or directory)
osql: problem: no potential directory strings in "/usr/local/bin/isql"
osql: advice: use "osql -I DIR" where DIR unixODBC\'s install prefix e.g. /usr/local
isql strings are:
checking odbc.ini files
    reading /Users/*****/.odbc.ini
[MyDSN] found in /Users/*****/.odbc.ini
found this section:
    [MyDSN]                                                                                                                
    Description         = testdb SQLServer DB
    Driver              = FreeTDS
    Trace               = Yes
    TraceFile           = /tmp/sql.log
    Database            = Places
    ServerName          = *****
    UserName            = *****
    Password            = *****
    Port                = 1433
    Protocol            = 7.2
    ReadOnly            = No
    RowVersioning       = No
    ShowSystemTables    = No
    ShowOidColumn       = No
    FakeOidIndex        = No
looking for driver for DSN [*****] in /Users/*****/.odbc.ini
  found driver line: "  Driver              = FreeTDS"
  driver "FreeTDS" found for [*****] in .odbc.ini
found driver named "FreeTDS"
"FreeTDS" is not an executable file
looking for entry named [FreeTDS] in /odbcinst.ini
grep: /odbcinst.ini: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure how to fix the problems that `isql` is reporting, but it seems to indicate that I have something misconfigured to me with odbc.  Unfortunately, I'm sorry that I don't know / remember precisely what I did to get it this way -- I've seriously been trying various things related to this on and off for weeks.

---

**Second update after mauro's comments.**

I've made a bit of progress.  I reinstalled both unixODBC and freeTDS (directly from http://www.unixodbc.org/ and http://www.freetds.org/ instead of using homebrew), and after doing so the output of my `odbc_config` commands matched mauro's output.

After some playing with my paths, I then was able to get both `osql` and `isql` to successfully connect to my SQL Server instance.  (I discovered one reason this was failing before was because the IT dept. in my organization was blocking all traffic to port 1433 when on the LAN.  When I switched to Wifi, like my Windows co-worker, it worked.)   I consider this great progress!

However, when I tried to import pyodbc from within python again, I got the exact same error message as I started out with.  Sigh.  So any other ideas would still be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, thank you to **@mauro** for his/her helpful and persistent suggestions.

After months of banging my head against walls, last night I was finally able to get this to work!

Here, I outline some of the key things (for me) in the hopes that these may be useful to others in the same predicament as I was.

BG.  Sometime a while ago (over a month), I read and attempted to do the things suggested [here](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2013/01/installing-debugging-odbc-on-mac-os-x/).  Although I don't clearly remember everyting I tried then, this led me to get `tsql` working and also, I think, to my having Homebrew versions of `unixODBC` and `freeTDS` installed.

Starting with my asking the question above, here are some of the things I tried that seemed to have had an impact.  (I'm not sure which things in particular were the most important, so I'm incuding everything.)  Points 1 and 2 are described above, so I won't dwell on them.

I. I re-installed `unixODBC` and `freeTDS` from their project web sites.

II. I discovered that port 1433 was being blocked on my LAN, so I switched to WiFi where it wasn't blocked.

These two things led to me being able to get `isql` and  `osql` to work.

III.  Reasoning that the `pyodbc` was failing to import in python due to something akin to a dynamic linking error.  I tried loading `/usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib` directly using both `dl.open()` and  `ctype.cdll.LoadLibrary()`.  In both cases, I got an error telling me:

```
dl.error: dlopen(libodbc.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

After some digging, thie led me to **recompile `unixODBC` for 32- instead of 64-bits** as follows:

```
sudo ./configure CFLAGS="-m32 -arch i386 -O2" LDFLAGS="-m32 -arch i386" CXXFLAGS="-m32 -arch i386"
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

At that point, I was able to explicitliy load `libodbc.dylib` using `dl.open()` and *finally* get pyodbc to import!!

IV. Unfortunately, without the explicit loading via `dl.open()`, the import still failed.  This led me to play with my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099981/why-cant-python-find-shared-objects-that-are-in-directories-in-sys-path)), but nothing seems to have worked yet.  So I'm still stuck using the `dl.open()` hack.

Furthermore, it still didn't work yet, failing related to the `freeTDS` driver when I tried to connect to a data source.  This finally led me to the following "working" hack-around:

```
import sys
if (sys.platform == 'darwin'):
    import dl
    _lib1 = dl.open("libodbc.dylib")                      # Found in /usr/local/lib
    _lib2 = dl.open("/opt/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so")
import pyodbc
```

Note that it was necessary to use the global variables `_lib1`  and `_lib2` to get it to work (I think in order to keep the stuff loaded).

At this point, things finally seem to be working well enough that I can use `pyodbc`!!

---

There were a few more things I tried along the way, but it's unclear to me if they helped or not.

- I also tried to compile `freeTDS` in 32-bit mode, similar to what I did for `unixODBC`, but I'm not sure if that worked.
- I downloaded, built and installed `pyodbc` from the github repo as opposed to using `pip`.  (It was the same version -- 3.0.10 -- as `pip` supplies though.)
- Per comment #10 [here](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=356), I added two lines to the `darwin` case of `setup.py` in the `pyodbc` source download (below) and re-ran `python.py setup.py build install`.

Like:

```
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':                                                                                        
    # The latest versions of OS X no longer ship with iodbc.  Assume
    # unixODBC for now.
    settings['libraries'].append('odbc')
    settings['include_dirs'] = ['/opt/local/include']              # Added this line
    settings['library_dirs'] = ['/opt/local/lib']                  # Added this line

    # Python functions take a lot of 'char *' that really should be const.  gcc complains about this *a lot*
    settings['extra_compile_args'].extend([
        '-Wno-write-strings',
        '-Wno-deprecated-declarations'
    ])

    # Apple has decided they won't maintain the iODBC system in OS/X and has added deprecation warnings in 10.8.
    # For now target 10.7 to eliminate the warnings.
    settings['define_macros'].append( ('MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7',) )

    settings['include_dirs'] = ['/opt/local/include']
    settings['library_dirs'] = ['/opt/local/lib']
```

- After I was all finished, I checked and I was also able to import and use `pypyodbc` *without* using the `dl.open()` hacks.  I'm not sure if all of the above steps were required for that to happen though.  I suspect the main issue was the 32- vs. 64-bit versions of the libraries.

---

Finally, although this wasn't related to the reasons I couldn't get `pyodbc` to import, I'll add a note about something that caused me to lose nearly an hour.  At some point I was attempting to follow the (very helpful) instructions at [this site](https://gist.github.com/Bouke/10454272).  However, I later discovered that the non-DSN connection string that the author showed did not work.  I instead had to use the FreeTDS connection attributes [shown here](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm) to get things to work.  For example:

```
"DRIVER=FreeTDS;Server=*****;Port=1433;TDS_Version=7.2;Database=*****;UID=*****;PWD=*****"
```

Although things are now working for me for the most part, I should mention that I'm now also sometimes getting the following error, for some of my query cursors, but I don't think it's related to any of the above.  (Instead, I suspect some sort of "timeout" issue on the connection. ...)

```
  ...
    for row in cursor:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 1920, in next
    row = self.fetchone()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 1914, in fetchone
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 986, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 966, in ctrl_err
    raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: (u'08S01', u'[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Bad token from the server: Datastream processing out of sync')
Exception pypyodbc.DatabaseError: DatabaseError(u'08S01', u'[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Write to the server failed') in <bound method Connection.__del__ of <pypyodbc.Connection instance at 0x60d5a8>> ignored
```

---

In summary, I think there were at least 3, if not 4, reasons why I couldn't use `pyodbc` in python.  The main two were related to 32- vs. 64-bit compilation of `unixODBC` and some library import path issue that I still don't really understand.

Good luck to anyone else who has to slog through all of this!

Comment: Hi Turix, I'm trying out your method by hard-setting _lib1 and _lib2. however, it keeps saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dl'" even tho i've installed it many times! :(

Comment: Hi @alwaysaskingquestions.  Looks like the `dl` module has been deprecated.  They have a message [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dl.html) saying to use the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) module instead.  I haven't tried this, but I imagine you'd use something like `ctypes.CDLL()`.  Good luck!!

Answer (score 3):

I agree... the very first thing to check in my opinion is the underlying ODBC layer.

You said you have installed unixODBC from sources on your Mac (like me). So check main unixODBC parameters using odbc_config (you should have it under `/usr/local/bin`):

```
$ odbc_config --version
2.3.4
$ odbc_config --libs
-L/usr/local/lib -lodbc
$ odbc_config --odbcini
/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
$ odbc_config --odbcinstini
/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
```

Then - I guess - you have created a Data Source for your ODBC database. Use another unixODBC utility (`isql`) to check you can connect to your database via ODBC:

```
$ sql <your_DSN> <your_DB_user> <your_DB_password> -v
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> quit
```

If everything is OK the unixODBC layer is ok.

**UPDATE**

Hmmm... you get this message:

```
...
checking odbc.ini files
reading /Users/*****/.odbc.ini
[MyDSN] found in /Users/*****/.odbc.ini
...
```

but the odic.ini location reported by unixODBC is different:

```
$ odbc_config --odbcini
/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbc.ini
```

I would also check which libraries are used by pyodbc. Here you have mine ones:

```
$ otool -L /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyodbc.so
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyodbc.so:
    /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

As you can see my pyodbc uses libodbc installed under `/usr/local/lib`. Exactly the location reported in my case by odic_config.

**SECOND UPDATE**

Good progress! So, to summarize, the current status is:

1. `isql DSN USER PASSWORD` works as expected
2. `import pyodbc` returns _SQLAllocHandle symbol not found. This means it doesn't find the right lib
3. `otool -L ...pyodbc.so` (same path as the one in 2.?) points the right lib

If this is the case I would re-install pyodbc (I did use `pip`) . I've heard the old version had problems to find the right headers/libs. Now that `isql` works... pyodbc should work as well.

Comment: Thanks!  I just added a bunch more details to my original question.  (Sorry I didn't add them to begin with.)  The fact that `isql` and `osql` don't work seems consistent with my having screwed up the ODBC install/configuration, but having never done that before, I'm in over my head with respect to how to fix it.

Comment: @Turix please check my UPDATE

Comment: Thanks for your update.  First, my output of the `otool` command is identical to yours.  As for the differing locations for the odbc.ini, I just added the contents of my `~/.odbc.ini` file into `/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini` as well as the Cellar one.  Didn't help.  I think the problems are more fundamental than finding the DSN anyway though.  (It can't even _import_ pyodbc... I haven't even gotten to the point of trying to connect to a DSN.)

Comment: @Turix what about re-installing unixODBC (latest version is 2.3.4) and re-configure it. I would focus on `pyodbc` only after getting `isql` up & running.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I did so and finally got both `osql` and `isql` to connect to my server.  Great!  Unfortunately, the problem with importing pyodbc still remains.  (I updated my question above to reflect this.)  Do you have any other suggestions?  (Thanks again for helping me get this far!)

Comment: @Turix. Good job. I did post a second update in my answer

Comment: Thanks, @mauro!  Last night, after hours of trying, I finally got it to work!  I posted an answer below.  In addition to re-installing pyodbc, I think the main issue was the `unixODBC` library needing to be compiled for 32 bit.  I really appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score -2):

Or......

`brew install unixodbc`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).