# failed to import google-python-cloud-debugger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

after installing
`sudo pip install google-python-cloud-debugger==1.10`

```
import googleclouddebugger

import cdbg_native as native
ImportError: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

the vm is a freshly installed machine

according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10986298/4391936
I have to updated my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. but I can't is my `/path/to/mysodir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing some dependencies like `python-dev`.

Try running something like this:

`sudo apt-get install curl ca-certificates gcc build-essential cmake \
    python python-dev libpython2.7 python-setuptools`