# Could someone explain this Python import error? Anaconda 3.5

Tags: python, r, import, interface, rpy2

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri, r
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/wayne/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "/home/wayne/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
ImportError: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director
```

Comment: By the way, would love to know the easiest way to format my code here.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099981/why-cant-python-find-shared-objects-that-are-in-directories-in-sys-path

Comment: In my experience, this kind of error comes up in Anaconda installations if the installation is somehow corrupted. Try uninstalling and re-installing rpy2