# Python can not find shared library that in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: python, import, shared-libraries

I have a python script that runs through MPI on a server. On importing `adios2` module, it crashes with the following error:

`ImportError: libhdf5.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

But when I run python in the CLI and try to import this module, it gives no error and imports properly.

The `libhdf5.so.10` itself is located at `/usr/lib64/libhdf5.so.10`

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100016/17101005) answer to the same question, I added `/usr/lib64` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but the problem remains.

How can I provide this shared library to python? Or, if anyone knows, could it be a problem with the ADIOS2 installation?

P.S. I can not run `ldconfig`, because I have no root permissions on the server.